# Load data on a web page based on what was clicked on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Is there any way that I can pass the id of an element from one HTML page to another? Essentially, I have a drop down with about 50 choices and based on what is clicked, I want my second HTML page to load data from my database corresponding to the user's choice.

I have a function on the second page that loads the data using an Ajax query. But is there a way to pass the id of what was clicked to that function? Or is there another way to do it?

I am using Django to populate the drop down menu and the other page.

Comment: that's where you'd use a form

Comment: Numerous ways... just do a web search.  The two most common ways are: 1) creating a form and submitting it to another page.  2) Requesting a new page and passing data in via a querystring.  That should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you guys =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a form and submit it to the second page.

```html
<form method="post" action="page2">
  <select>
    <option value=1> Option 1 </option>
    <option value=2> Option 2 </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: And how does that help? What do you do on the second page?

Answer (score 1):

Add a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to your link's address, and then in JS (or PHP) have code be executed conditionally, based on the query string.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options:
1) Use a form and submit
2) Pass in using QueryString

**[here's some more info on both](http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/tutoring/soen287/tutorials/query-strings-and-forms/)**